# Проблема с веб приложением Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Имеется Spring boot веб приложение. При запуске с IntelliJ Idea сервер стартует, все работает нормально. После сборки проекта через Maven сервер запускается, но при заходе через браузер выдает ошибку. В консоле пишет что не удается найти указанный шаблон. Думаю, вся проблема в пути к файлу шаблона. Но как правильно поправить не знаю. Вот контроллер начальной страницы.

```
 @RequestMapping({"/persons","/","/index"})
    public String getAllPersons(Model model) throws NotFoundException {
        model.addAttribute(PERSONS, personService.findAll());
        log.debug("I'm at getAllPersons");
        return "/index";
    }
```

Comment: Метод контроллера должен возвращать имя шаблона, а не URL. В вашем случае скорее всего просто "index".

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо. Дайте ответ, чтоб я закрыл вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы возвращаете `URL`, когда должны вернуть имя вашего шаблона. Скорее всего, он называется `index`. Исправьте это в поле `return` и все должно заработать.